# Wired 360 controller constantly vibrates on some PSX games [Retro Pi]

Tags: retropie

I have a wired 360 controller working fine with my Retro Pi on most PSX games, however I have a couple where once the game loads, the controller constantly vibrates. My games are running in .PBP format but before converting I tested them in .cue/bin and the vibrating issue still occurs. Any idea how I can fix this? I don't want to disable the vibration as it works fine in the majority of my games.

I tried installing the driver xboxdrv but the issue is still occurring.

I am running Retro Pi 4.2

Cheers.

Comment: If vibration's fine in some games, but not in others, it's reasonably likely that the issue's in the games rather than in RetroPie. I'd suggest trawling the [RetroPie forum](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/) and [Github](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/issues) to see if anyone's experiencing the same issues with the same games.

Answer (score -2):

I started to use recalbox for this reason alone. Since I switch it hasn't been a problem.